# Magento 2 : Custom extension install and update composer require using public and private key

Tags: magento2, composer, git

I have created the custom extension for my client and the client want to install and update the custom extension like Amasty and Aheadworks.

So can anyone give any reference URL and how can I do the below thing?

> how can i create custom composer url like "repo.magento.com",
> "https://composer.amasty.com/community/",
> "https://dist.aheadworks.com/"?

> How can I add the Composer access token like public and private key?

Comment: i also use "packagist.com" but in that, I can not find a key-based system.

Comment: Please go through this documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html#private_repos

Comment: I tried this "https://packagist.com/" website but it is not asking for any public or private key. I also checked in the packagist setting but in that also they are not providing access keys section

Comment: @Kushal packagist is paid. You can try https://github.com/vtsykun/packeton